# Passing Array into Unmanaged Code for Modification

Tags: c#, c++, memory-management

I have an array allocated in `C#` which I am passing into unmanaged code to be modified. The following code works, but I am not sure if there are any other more 'correct' or 'efficient' methods that I am not aware of.

**Code.c**

```
extern "C" {
    class MyObject
    {
    public:
        int32_t X;
    };

    __declspec(dllexport) void ArrayTest(MyObject* a, int length);

    void ArrayTest(MyObject* a, int length)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            a[i].X = i + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

**Code.cs**

```
class Program
{
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct MyObject
    {
        public Int32 X;
    }

    [DllImport(@"MyDll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public extern static void ArrayTest(IntPtr objects, int length);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var objects = new MyObject[3];

        var handle = GCHandle.Alloc(objects, GCHandleType.Pinned);
        var ptr = GCHandle.ToIntPtr(handle);

        ArrayTest(ptr, objects.Length);

        for (int i = 0; i < objects.Length; i++)
        {
            var offset = Marshal.SizeOf<MyObject>() * i;

            objects[i] = Marshal.PtrToStructure<MyObject>(IntPtr.Add(ptr, offset));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `extern "C" class`?  C only has `struct`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must definitely call `handle.Free()` when finished using it so `GC` can do the cleaning.

---

Note that `GCHandle.Alloc(objects, GCHandleType.Pinned);` only works for structs with pure primitive or to be more precise: blittable types. String fields etc. must be handled differently.

---

A little optimization:

You repeatedly calculate this

> `var offset = Marshal.SizeOf<MyObject>() * i;`

Instead you can calculate `offset` once:

```
var offset = Marshal.Sizeof<MyObject>();
```

and in the loop do:

```
ptr = IntPtr.Add(ptr, offset);
```

---

If you are willing/allowed to run in `unsafe` mode you can do:

```
unsafe public void RunUnsafe()
{
  var objects = new MyObject[3];

  var handle = GCHandle.Alloc(objects, GCHandleType.Pinned);
  var ptr = GCHandle.ToIntPtr(handle);

  ArrayTest(ptr, objects.Length);
  MyObject* pobj = (MyObject*)ptr;

  for (int i = 0; i < objects.Length; i++, pobj++)
  {
    Console.WriteLine((*pobj).X);
  }

  handle.Free();
}
```

---

If you are entitled to modify the signature of `ArrayTest`, you can changed it to:

```
    public extern static void ArrayTest([In, Out] MyObject[] objects, int length);
```

The `[In, Out]` attributes determines that the array should be marshaled both ways so that `ArrayTest` can work on the provided instances in the array `[In]`, and changes made in `ArrayTest` are reflected in the objects when the function returns `[Out]`.

Then your method can be simplified to:

```
  var objects = new MyObject[3];

  ArrayTest(objects, objects.Length);

  foreach (var obj in objects)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(obj.X);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks. So using `[In, Out]` won't require pinning?

Comment: @rhughes: No, the marshaler handles that - as far as I know.